# Fixing http tag in Spring bean config file

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

My bean configuration file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 ">


</beans:beans>
```

I am not being able to add the following into it though I have imported security 3.1.1 jar

```
<http> 
  <intercept-url pattern='/home*' access='ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN' />
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the `security` namespace.  The alternative is to make `security` the default namespace - you'll have to decide if you want to do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/home*' access='ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN'/>
    </security:http>    
</beans:beans>
```

Not only have I added `security:` to the front of the tags you've used, but I've added xmlns:security at the top, along with its schema location.

Comment: Thank you. but a warning just came up. Unable to locate Spring namespace handler for element     security:http

Comment: Please explain: what IDE are you using?  Are you writing a servlet or your own runnable jar?  Please show the code that you're using to run everything.

Comment: The problem has been resolved by adding `security:` at the beginning of each and every sub tag as `security:logout`